# AngularUI Modal not rendering http fetched data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to embed [AngularUI modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) to one of my web page.

This function fetches data using HTTP get request.

```
$scope.fetchTimings=function(){
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'get/xyz'
})
    .success(function(data) {
            return data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        return {};
    });

};
```

This is the variable that I am passing to modal:

```
$scope.newCategory={
  title:'xyz',
  openHours: $scope.fetchTimings()
}
```

Controller:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
templateUrl: "addcategory.html",
controller: "addCategoryModalInstanceCtrl",
resolve: {
    newCategory: function() {
        return $scope.newCategory;
    }
}
});
```

Modal Instal Controller:

```
.controller('addCategoryModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, newCategory) {
    $scope.newCategory = newCategory;
    $scope.addedNewCategory = $scope.newCategory;
    $scope.ok = function() {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.addedNewCategory);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
})
```

View:
In view,
{{newCategory.title}} is being rendered,
while 
{{newCategory.openHours}} shows empty objects.

I guess, this is related to some async delay.
How can I fix this problem?

-Thanks

Comment: fetchTimings always returns nothing, i mean there is no return statement -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what resolve is meant for, it wil keep your controller waiting untill everything in there is resolved:

Controller:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: "addcategory.html",
    controller: "addCategoryModalInstanceCtrl",
    resolve: {
        newCategory: function() {
            return $scope.newCategory;
        },
        timings: ['$http', function($http){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/someUrl'
            });
        }]
    }
});
```

Modal instance controller:

```
.controller('addCategoryModalInstanceCtrl',
    function($scope, $modalInstance, newCategory, timings) {
        $scope.timings = timings;
        $scope.newCategory = newCategory;
        $scope.addedNewCategory = $scope.newCategory;
        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.addedNewCategory);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }
)
```

See the reference for ui-router resolve: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve